# take a picture with expo camera

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to take a picture for a `React-Native Expo` application, but I can't figure it out and the following answer on stack overflow isn't helping: [How to snap pictures using expo react native camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707002/how-to-snap-pictures-using-expo-react-native-camera).

I got my code mostly from the expo demo on their site (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#takepictureasync) with the exception of I added a picture button I want to use to take a picture.  Can someone please help me out?

I have already tried working with the above-mentioned stack overflow help, and it isn't working.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
    import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
    import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
    
    export default class CameraExample extends React.Component {
      state = {
        hasCameraPermission: null,
        type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
      };
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
      }
    
      render() {
        const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
        if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
          return <View />;
        } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
          return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
        } else {
          return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                  }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                      flex: 0.1,
                      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.setState({
                        type:
                          this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                            ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                            : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
                      });
                    }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}> Flip </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity> 
                  <Image source={require("./images/camera.jpeg")}
                  style={{width: 100,
                  height: 100}} /> /* this is my button for taking the picture*/
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </Camera>
            </View>
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

I just want to snap a picture and display to the console for now.

Answer (score 3):

in this part of your code, you need set a onPress action to "snap" a picture.
My suggestion is simple as to add a

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => takePicture()}> 
     <Image source={require("./images/camera.jpeg")} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
 </TouchableOpacity>`

And add the Async function to receive the actual picture:

```
 const takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
        const options = {quality: 1, base64: true};
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        console.log(data);
    }
};
```

Go to your terminal and you have there your log with Image BASE64 Image.

I hope this helped you :)

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Almeida!